# PHP preg_replace with references passed to functions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, urlencode

I am using `preg_replace()` in PHP with references. The problem is when the `$1` reference is passed into another function *(in this case `escapeContent()`)* the value at run time is `$1` instead of the actual replaced value. See the following:

```
function escapeContent($input) {
    return urlencode($input);
}

$content = '{{include:rec_ABXtI504839d1a607c1MI}}';
$content_smart_linked = preg_replace('/\{\{ ?include:([a-zA-Z0-9_]{25}) ?\}\}/i', '<a href="' . escapeContent('$1') . '">{{include:$1}}</a>', $content);
echo $content_smart_linked;
```

The `echod` result of `$content_smart_linked` is:

```
 <a href="%241">{{include:rec_ABXtI504839d1a607c1MI}}</a>
```

Notice `urlencode()` ran on `$1`, thus turning it into `%241`, instead of `rec_ABXtI504839d1a607c1MI`. If I remove `urlencode()` and just `return $input`, it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: use preg_replace_callback

Comment: Don't need a callback, I want the standard behavior of replace.

Comment: Then good luck with it? Otherwise you have to do something like `preg_match_all()` yourself and iterate over further replacements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **[preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)**:

```
$content = '{{include:rec_ABXtI504839d1a607c1MI}}';
$content_smart_linked = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{ ?include:([a-zA-Z0-9_]{25}) ?\}\}/i', 
function($matches) {
   return '<a href="' . escapeContent($matches[1]) . '">{{include:'.$matches[1].'}}</a>';
},
$content);
echo $content_smart_linked;
```

Otherwise you need to use the **DEPRECATED** `"\e"` modifier which is highly not recommended (E_DEPRECATED will be emitted).

Comment: Ok, that seems to have worked. Quite counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Justin the "e" modifier is "more intuitive" for you but as **xdazz** mentioned, it has been deprecated. It's a potential security risk since it's eval'ing the replacement code - including whatever `$1` may have in it. So in light of that, IMO `preg_replace_callback` is a rather nice function. Note, you don't *have* to have an inline anonymous function for it; you can define a function separately and pass the (string) function name as the arg instead. But doing it this way has the added benefit of letting you pass other vars through the use of `use` without using global vars